# How to make my autocomplete chrome extension work?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have created a code that gives me different standard answers i always use when i'm working. The code is simple but it will make me more efficient ...if is doable. The standard phrases have tag names and if i open the browser i'll get an "userBox", if i type in "moving" i'll get the phrase for that tag name. I've created a chrome extension that "matches": [""] but i want the tag names to be triggered and to give me the corresponding phrase automatically when i write an email. I have no experience with chrome extensions and i'm a beginner in js and html, is this doable for a beginner and if so i would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently working on a similar project, the first task for you would be to get the contentEditable divs and textarea using querySelector, the divs and textarea inside iframe should be handled separately and listen for the changes made in the textarea. if you want to alter DOM or get something from DOM it should go in content scripts read more about it [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in Chrome extension documentation and know the difference between content scripts and [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) scripts. Try starting with simple extensions like background-color changing extension to get the hang of it. JS for beginers might be confusing since its asynchronous, so I recommend doing some simple extensions first and get familarised with chrome extension API.